# Java - Записывать ВСЁ, что выполняется программой в файл Log

Tags: java

Как сделать так, чтобы всё, что выполняется в данный момент моей программой, записывалось в файл `file.log`? Например:

Исходный код

```
JFrame main = new JFrame("main");
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http:\\myurl\\file.txt").openConnection().getInputStream()));
String str = r.readLine();
```

В файле лога должно быть что-то вроде этого

```
java.Swing.JFrame main = new java.Swing.JFrame("main");
String str = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(new java.net.URL("http:\\myurl\\file.txt").openConnection().getInputStream())).readLine();
```

Мне это нужно, чтобы при возникновении какой-либо ошибки, я мог посмотреть в файл лог, увидеть всё, что выполнялось программой, и, соответственно, понять в чём ошибка.

Comment: Любая мало-мальски годная IDE предоставляет достаточно инструментов для отладки: брэйкпойнты, вотчеры, пошаговое выполнение, стектрейсы , логгеры, профилировщики, трасировщики и прочее прочее .. почему вы решили отлаживать программу каким то своим, неведомым, способом?

Comment: Так это же и есть ваш исходный код

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> чтобы при возникновении какой-либо ошибки, я мог посмотреть

Если такая необходимость возникла только для этих случаев воспользуйтесь методом [`printStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28java.io.PrintWriter%29).

Например так:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

class Test {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        PrintWriter log;
        FileWriter logFile;
        /*  Сначала откроем файл, в который будем писать ошибки */
        try {
            logFile = new FileWriter("exceptions.log", true);
            log = new PrintWriter((java.io.Writer)logFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        try {
        /*  Тут находится основной код вашего приложения. Ошибки будут
            проявляться в виде исключений, например так (искуственный
            пример)
        */
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        /*  Перехватываем все необработанные исключения и пишем в логфайл
            временную отметку, сообщение об ошибке и стектрейс (в котором
            будут указаны методы, которые привели к ошибке и номера строк
            в исходниках)
        */
            log.printf("\n%s: %s\n", LocalDateTime.now(), ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace(log);
            log.flush();
        }
    }
}
```